# SONY DSC T99G Vs Sony DCS H55 Camera

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I am Planning to purchase the a cybershot camera can any one suggest which one would be a better choice as between DSC T99g or H55 as both are priced equally with major diff at 
1) Zoom ie 10x Vs 4x
2) non touch screen Vs Touch screen
3) And about HD Recording in camera.

Comment: You probably ought to write a little about what you want to use the camera for (landscapes, portraits, nights out etc) and what hope to get out of it. Without more info, you'll only get subjective answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is common for manufacturer to use the same sensor in a compact and an ultra-slim camera as this is the case. That is why the specifications seem similar but in terms of features these are quite different, mostly in favor of the larger H55:

- Longer zoom, as you mentioned.
- Manual exposure
- Shutter-speeds up to 30s, needed for night photography (use of a tripod is necessary)
- Faster continuous drive (1.8 FPS vs 0.7)
- Better battery life (310 shots vs 230)
- They both record 720p HD video

BTW, you can see the any number of cameras side by side by searching for the specifications you are looking for using the [camera finder](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) at neocamera.com.

To see those two cameras, simply follow [this link](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?megapixels=14:min&brand=sony&focalwide=24:to:26).